# Proper usage of Classes and Functions

Tags: oop, class, theory

I taken over site from another developer, he was putting everything in functions inside class files.

e.g. page lists system users **our_users.php**

```
$users = $object_user -> get_users_list();
```

and function `get_users_list()` is NOT used anywhere else on website.

Does that make sny sense to to do it this way?

I'd personally would not even create function and just put code from inside function `get_users_list()` in **our_users.php** since its only used once anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the guiding principles of OOP currently is the concept of "separation of concerns".  This means that you pull out small units of work into their own methods and classes.  The idea  of having one method that does a hundred things directly is the antithesis of this.

Splitting the functionality out makes your code easier to read, maintain and test.

There are a number of blog posts on the web about OOP best practices - [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) being the driving one at the moment.  If you look them up I'm sure any number of them can do a better job of describing them than I could.

Comment: What you mean by "method that does a hundred things" as i understand method is function that exists inside Class? 
Yap i guess you mean that he uses big functions with bunch of code (sometimes 500 line in function) that repeats in many other functions as well.

I agree only functions should only do something that usable again and again even.

Comment: ...I agree functions should only do something that usable again and again. 

Otherwise it makes no sense to create one if you just copy part of the page **our_users.php** that displays users, or another part that creates user, inside function.  then you got this monster functions for each page that doubles code and makes it spaghetti.

Answer (score 0):

OOP not only makes code easier to reuse, it also helps group like functionality and ensures other developers aren't lost when they try to understand your work. IMO you'd be shooting yourself in the foot if you start tearing apart a previous developer's structure.

Comment: Have to do because its so fre***g confusing to work with the site in that way, he calls functions some not obvious names.

I use OOP as well except again i dont see why i put code inside function if that function and future-more function that stored in some other file when its only has 1 call total to that function.